# Does golden chest disappear after using a key on a character?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have read somewhere that you cannot use a key a second time on the same character ie. you use it, boom, golden chest disappears for that character forever.

Is this really true?

Sorry if this question is a bit too less informative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is specifically how it goes down:

You try and open the chest, and a prompt comes up asking if you're sure you want to expend a key (the *key* is gone forever). The key is consumed and the chest opens, holding a Red Chest's worth of loot, but everything is Purple or Magenta (not sure if Orange can spawn there, if it does it's crazy rare). You can open the chest again immediately for more loot only after you've removed all items from the opened chest (you can just pick them up and drop them or sell them).

The chest remains in Sanctuary and can be reopened any time with a golden key after the platform has been lowered.

Comment: Items in the chest are [always purple](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=147008) (E-tech/Magenta counts as purple also) and are tuned to your level when you open it. "See, the loot inside the Golden Chest is always of 'very rare' (purple) quality and scaled to your character’s level at the moment you open the chest."

Answer (score 9):

No, this is not true. The *key* disappears, not the golden chest.

Answer (score 1):

The golden chest in Sanctuary is a persistent item and will not disappear even after multiple uses on the same character. The only thing you lose is a golden key every time you open the chest.